# VC++ & Boost- BOOST_INTERLOCKED_INCREMENT is undefined

Tags: visual-c++, boost, compilation, undefined

I am not familiar with C++, and try to study some sample code. However, when I import project and try to debug it, VC++ shows error below. It means identifier "BOOST_INTERLOCKED_INCREMENT" is undefined.

My Application & C++ Libraries:

1. Boost: boost_1_57_0-msvc-10.0-32
2. CGAL-4.0.2
3. Visual Studio 2010 Express (30 day trial)
4. OpenSSL 1.01j
5. ZLIB 1.2.8

..\Library\Olap\Commitable.cpp(43): error C3861: 'BOOST_INTERLOCKED_INCREMENT': identifier not found
..\Library\Olap\Commitable.cpp(53): error C3861: 'BOOST_INTERLOCKED_DECREMENT': identifier not found

I am wonder if anymore can help me to solve the problem or not. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your sample code is missing an include - try to add this to the beginning of `Library\Olap\Commitable.cpp`

```
#include <boost/detail/interlocked.hpp>
```

According to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/detail/interlocked.hpp), that is where the two missing macros are defined.